# How to solve the integral $I_n=\int_{0}^{1}x^n\sqrt{1-x}$?

Tags: definite-integrals, recurrence-relations

Let $I_n=\int_{0}^{1}x^n\sqrt{1-x}$. I need to find a recurrence relation, but I do not see any way to do it. Can you help me?[image]

Comment: Partial integration is the way to go.

Comment: @Math_QED I tried but I do not get anything good. Maybe I do something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By integration by parts, for $n \geq 1$

\begin{align*}
I_n
&= \left[ -\frac{2}{3}x^n (1-x)^{3/2} \right]_{0}^{1} + \frac{2n}{3} \int_{0}^{1} x^{n-1}(1-x)^{3/2} \, dx \\
&= \frac{2n}{3} \int_{0}^{1} x^{n-1}(1-x)\sqrt{1-x} \, dx \\
&= \frac{2n}{3}(I_{n-1} - I_n).
\end{align*}

Solving this in terms of $I_n$, we obtain

$$ I_n = \frac{2n}{2n+3} I_{n-1}.\tag{*} $$

---

*Remark.* Using the gamma function, it follows from the beta function identity that

$$ I_n = B\left( n+1, \tfrac{3}{2} \right) = \frac{n!(\frac{1}{2})!}{(n+\frac{3}{2})!}. $$

Using this we also confirm that $\text{(*)}$ holds.

Answer (score 7):

Observe that
$$\begin{align}
I_n &=\int_0^1 x^n\sqrt{1-x}dx\\
&=\int_0^1 x^n(1-x)\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x}}\\
&=\int_0^1 x^n\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x}}-\int_0^1 x^{n+1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x}}\\
&= J_n-J_{n+1}
\end{align}$$
... if we define $J_n$ as follows:
$$J_n := \int_0^1 x^n\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x}}$$
It follows by IBP that
$$\begin{align}
J_n
&=\int_0^1 x^n\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x}}\\
&=\bigg[-2x^n\sqrt{1-x}\bigg]_0^1 +2n\int_0^1 x^{n-1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x}}\\
&=2n\int_0^1 x^{n-1}\sqrt{1-x}dx\\
&=2nI_{n-1}\\
\end{align}$$
So we have
$$I_n=J_n-J_{n+1}$$
and
$$J_n=2nI_{n-1}$$
Thus, we have
$$I_n=2nI_{n-1}-2(n+1)I_n$$
$$(2n+3)I_n=2nI_{n-1}$$
and so
$$\color{green}{I_n=\frac{2n}{2n+3}I_{n-1}}$$

Comment: @SangchulLee All better now! You're right, it *was* a sign error. Thanks!

Comment: Now it looks fine :) (+1)

Comment: How is $int_0^1 x^{n-1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x}}\\ &=\int_0^1 x^{n-1}\sqrt{1-x}dx$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\sqrt{1-x}=\cos t, x=\sin^2t\implies dx=2\sin t\cos t\ dt$

$$I_n=\int_0^1x^n\sqrt{1-x}dx=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2n}t\cos t(2\sin t\cos t\ dt)$$

$$=2\int\cos^2t\sin^{2n+1}t\ dt=B(x,y)$$

where $2x-1=2\iff x=?,2y-1=2n+1\iff$

See [Beta Function](https://brilliant.org/wiki/beta-function/#trigonometric-representation-of-the-beta-function)